# Input and output for AWK

Tags: loops, for-loop, awk

I am trying to run this for-loop and just seeking some feedback on what it is supposed to do:

```
for FF in `cat bams`
do
F=$(basename $FF)
F_PREFIX=${F/.bam/}
angsd -i $F -anc $GENOME_REF $FILTERS -GL 1 -doSaf 1 -doCounts 1 -out ${F_PREFIX} && realSFS ${F_PREFIX}.saf.idx >${F_PREFIX}.ml | awk -v file=$F '{print file\"\t\"(\$1+\$2+\$3)\"\t\"\$2/(\$1+\$2+\$3)}' ${F_PREFIX}.ml >> goodbams.goodsites.het
done
```

The issue I have is piping the output to awk.
Can someone comment if the input file (file=$F) is the original file under

```
F/.bam
```

or

```
{F_PREFIX}.saf.idx
```

or

```
${F_PREFIX}.ml
```

I am also unclear what the second ${F_PREFIX}.ml is supposed to do in the awk script.

This to me looks like the .saf.idx output should be stored in the ${F_PREFIX}.ml file, and then awk should execute the command using the ${F/.bam/} file and also put the output into ${F_PREFIX}.ml.
Then those total ${F_PREFIX}.ml output should go into goodbams.goodsites.het

Would someone be able to confirm that interpretation?

Comment: Please add a suitable shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) and then paste your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Answer (score 0):

To get this to work, I had to break it into multiple chunks:
First the full script, which only the angsd command worked -

```
for FF in `cat bams`
do
F=$(basename $FF)
F_PREFIX=${F/.bam/}
angsd -i $F -anc $GENOME_REF $FILTERS -GL 1 -doSaf 1 -doCounts 1 -out ${F/.bam/} && realSFS ${F/.bam/}.saf.idx | awk -v file=$F '{print file\"\t\"(\$1+\$2+\$3)\"\t\"\$2/(\$1+\$2+\$3)}' ${F/.bam/}.ml >> goodbams.goodsites.het
done
```

Then

```
for FF in `cat bams`;
do
F=$(basename $FF)
F_PREFIX=${F/.bam/}
realSFS ${F/.bam/}.saf.idx > ${F_PREFIX}.ml
done
```

then

```
for FF in `cat bams`;
do
F=$(basename $FF)
F_PREFIX=${F/.bam/}
eval "awk -v file=$F '{print file\"\t\"(\$1+\$2+\$3)\"\t\"\$2/(\$1+\$2+\$3)}' ${F/.bam/}.ml" >> goodbams.goodsites.het
done
```

All performed in indev mode